# Short way of saying pre-exterior (of a line or order)

Tags: single-word-requests, colloquialisms

Actually, I'm looking for a short version of a collection of highly related words:

- Pre-exterior (before the beginning)
- Pre-interior (after the beginning)
- Post-exterior (after the ending)
- Post-interior (before the ending)

The objective is to provide *names* for a small piece of a computer program that handle things in an order or a "line" with say "sub-lines"

Imagine this situation:

you have a line within a line. people within the bigger line, that are not in the "sub-line" are denoted with the character "A" vs where the "sub-line" people are denoted with the character "a" like this:

A | A | A | *`A | a`* | a | a | a | a | a | a| a | a | **`a | A`** | A | A

I am looking to name each of these characters: the *italicized "A"*, the *italicized "a"*, the **bold "A"**, and the **bold "a"**

Comment: Actually I did some digging and found the words "anterior" and "posterior." however these words could be used for either the interior or exterior words.

Comment: More digging: "preceding" and "succeeding" could be used for the "exterior" words. Now what about the "interior" words?

Comment: So, I guess what I am looking for now is a word for "before the end" and "after the beginning"

Comment: Perhaps "initiating" and "terminating" could work?

Comment: It's not quite clear how this is to be used.  Is this similar to a subroutine call?  Perhaps, "sub-line insertion point" (*A*), "sub-line entry point" (*a*), "sub-line completion point" (**a**), "main-line continuation point" (**A**)

Comment: @Jim The usage is for in a program (script actually: JavaScript). It's to name certain parts of an array. There is a _subsection_ of the array that the program "has interest in." The program will do something with the _subsection_, but in order to do that, it needs to identify those 4 pieces, and the pieces of the program that identify those 4 parts of the array are extremely complex. So I would like to be able to easily remember what those sections of the code do when I go to review the code for bugs, I could use a way to name them (and put the name in comments inside the code of course)

Answer (score -1):

First, second, third, ... [stuff in the middle] ... antepenultimate, penultimate, ultimate (or last)

Comment: This doesn't work given the requirements of the question.